# React-d3-tree Zoom and Drag Not Working on Next.js 13

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, next.js, react-hooks, next.js13

I'm working on a Next.js 13 project using the react-d3-tree library for rendering a tree structure. I've added the zoom and drag properties to my tree component, but I'm encountering an issue where these features are not working consistently on the client side. Initially, it worked once, but now it's not working at all.

Here's my **roadmap.tsx** file:

```
"use client"

import Tree from 'react-d3-tree';
import { Node } from '../utils/d3/interfaces/Node';

// ... (other code)

export default function Roadmap({ data }: RoadmapProps) {
    // ... (other code)

    return (
        <section>
            <div id="treeWrapper" style={{ width: '80vw', height: '100vh', overflow: 'hidden' }}>
                <Tree
                    data={data}
                    zoomable={true}
                    scaleExtent={{ max: 1, min: 0.1 }}
                    draggable={true}
                    translate={{ x: 600, y: 100 }}
                    orientation="vertical"
                    pathFunc="step"
                />
            </div>
        </section>
    )
}
```

And here's my **page.tsx** file:

```
// ... (other code)

export default async function Home() {
    // ... (other code)

    return (
        <main className="max-w-7xl mx-auto lg:px-16 px-6 bg-slate-400">
            <Roadmap data={nodes} />
        </main>
    )
}
```

Here is sample data:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Checkpoint 2",
    "attribute": {
      "id": "18f7db92-b5cf-46b5-9641-08ceac16ca6e"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Checkpoint 1",
        "attribute": {
          "id": "658d0c4b-2726-47a6-8053-b2ffd8eb2502"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Checkpoint 6",
            "attribute": {
              "id": "0d59cdcd-e159-4f52-a3e9-1ddaa32fff0f"
            },
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Checkpoint 7",
            "attribute": {
              "id": "a61d8a27-1228-4eb1-94ea-5edc6678c1b4"
            },
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Checkpoint 3",
        "attribute": {
          "id": "be69ab2b-11c6-423e-9fe1-b9c46c4c37f4"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Checkpoint 8",
            "attribute": {
              "id": "59078d99-512c-4413-96bf-0e237fbe4dca"
            },
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Checkpoint 9",
            "attribute": {
              "id": "f7dee6d8-e56a-4bc5-9c25-e5eb098aa53f"
            },
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Checkpoint 4",
        "attribute": {
          "id": "0b24d129-c75c-4d07-b350-6ead198e6237"
        },
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "name": "Checkpoint 5",
        "attribute": {
          "id": "342c95c1-256f-488a-94a7-e4f3a56ec2cf"
        },
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I'm using Next.js 13 and the react-d3-tree library. I'm seeking advice on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue, so that the zoom and drag functionality works consistently on the client side. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have the same issue, actually in the first load page, it does not work, but when I move the code block of <Tree> component out of its container and save, after the hot reload it works fine, obviously it’s not working when I make the deploy as well. :/